# Programming a Scratch like Software (in terms of UI / framework) for Hardware Interfacing

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mit-scratch

So I am an engineer and we are working on basic robotic kit (arduino, motors and stuff) for kids, we are based in Karachi, Pakistan and this is where our target market is.

We want to provide a software along with the kit - the software needs to be like scratch but scratch is geared more towards learning on computer, we want the software to be centered around a hardware robot.

We have looked at several implementations of Scratch, from

- MiroBot (mirobot.io) - uses SNAP, scratch like software
- mBot (mblock.cc/mbot) - they also made the ScratchBot
  (app.makeblock.cc/program/scratch/) - not opensource, based on
  scratch flash
- Mind+ (www.mindplus.cc/index.html) - opensource,
  looking at it

We also looked at Node/Flow based Programming, however we are mainly electronics engineers and although we can do Desktop applications we need to know what this sort of applications are called and is there any framework or tools or libraries we can use to make SNAP-able blocks and allow a rich colorful programming environment to kids - We want to keep it open source but want to make it ourselves so we have a complete grasp on things. Modifying/Hacking scratch source files is not an option for us as it is based on Flex/Flash and we dont want to use Flex.

Any help or pointers or advice or opinions are welcome in this regard as to from where we should start and how.

What we want for now is a basic software with Arduino language implemented as BLOCKS and which connects seamlessly with the hardware (COM PORT communication/detection) without requiring the kid to find the right COM port and connect and stuff.

Comment: Sorry, your question is way too broad to get a concise answer here. Have a look at this article from the Help Center please: [What topics can I ask here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: maybe I wrote a lot, basically what I want to ask is how would one go about creating a software which allows BLOCK PROGRAMMING / DATAFLOW PROGRAMMING capabilities to the user.

Comment: At least the [tag:c++] tag is reserved for specific programming problem questions related to code. Check our [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) please.

Comment: block programming is programming, regardless that grown-ups do not use it. It is appropriate for this forum and the tags given.

Answer (score 2):

There exists a "blockly for arduino" open source tool - blockly is like Scratch, except that you can create new blocks etc. to adapt the tool to the children.

The github page for blocklyduino: https://github.com/gasolin/BlocklyDuino

Answer (score 2):

[Google's Blockly](https://developers.google.com/blockly/), open source [on GitHub](https://github.com/google/blockly), is the foundation of numerous block-based programming apps for robotics kits (including mBot's and the BlocklyDuino boisvert mentioned). The platform it well supported with plenty of documentation and examples, an active community, and continuing development. It is also the foundation of the upcoming Scratch 3.0.

Comment: As of Scratch 3.0 (released in January 2019), Scratch's block coding is now built upon Google's Blockly.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a Scratch extension:
https://github.com/LLK/scratchx/wiki

http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/wiki/Scratch_Extension

http://wiki.scratch.mit.edu/w/images/ExtensionsDoc.HTTP-9-11.pdf